# Osmdroid retrieve nearest marker

Tags: java, android, osmdroid

I have a map with tons of markers included in a JSON file.

Is there any way to get the *nearest marker* (Geopoint) between me and **x** marker ? *(for example, if I want to have only 3 markers in the map + my position)*

I see that Open Street Map has a [server-side api](https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki/Server-api) but I cannot use it in the project (no network).

I digged a little more and saw that there is something in osmbonuspack interesting : [POI](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/wiki/Tutorial_2) and we can find the nearest POI. So maybe something exist for marker ?
Lot of thanks
!